# Serving Partial HTTP Response

Tags: http, httprequest, http-1.1

I would like to make a file download resumable using byte-range requests.

The problem is that my existing download action is responding on a POST method and I would like to keep it that way.

But it seems from my early tests that Chrome turns interrupted `POST` requests for file downloads into `GET` requests when the user tries to resume and thus the resuming of the download fails.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is this something related to the HTTP specs that only allow `GET` requests to be resumed?
3. Or is it simply a design flaw in Chrome (and maybe other browsers as well) that makes it forget the original HTTP method used?

**UPDATE:**

Here are the request/response data:

Initial POST request:

```
POST http://localhost:35547/Download?Guid=396b4697-e275-4396-818c-548bf8c0a281 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:35547
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:35547
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:35547/File/396b4697-e275-4396-818c-548bf8c0a281
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=LuPgM05MHrsuyskgfhsrHVUs; ASP.NET_SessionId=gfiulghfuygisghkf; .ASPXAUTH=FGDJHGDHSDFB15AFDE6371CGJHDFGFBHD; fileDownload=true
```

Initial response (to the request above):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/zip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILE-396b4697e2754396818c548bf8c0a281.zip"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 11:13:50 GMT
Content-Length: 1885473

PK.......... ZIP file data .............................................
```

After the interruption, this is the request that the browser does on resume (notice the `GET` method used):

```
GET http://localhost:35547/Download?Guid=396b4697-e275-4396-818c-548bf8c0a281 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:35547
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:35547/File/396b4697-e275-4396-818c-548bf8c0a281
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=.............
```

(Some data from security-related cookies have been shortened and altered)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the exact request/responses that occur.

Comment: @JulianReschke I have added those now, as an update to the question. :) Apart from the HTTP method used, I don't see it using range headers either, which is also weird...

Comment: *How* does the user try to resume the download? Also, I wouldn't expect a client to try to resume unless there's a validator (Last-Modified or Etag), and maybe even Accept-Ranges.

Comment: @JulianReschke Right. The reason it used no byte range header when resuming was the lack of the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header. I have added a `Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:01:00 GMT` header as well and it now sends a byte range header. But still, it uses a GET request when resuming. To test this, I interrupt the download using the `offline` checkbox from Chrome's dev tools. Then I click the `resume` option on the failed download from Chrome's built-in download manager (after I uncheck the `offline` checkbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something ?

It depends, upon how have you analyzed the behavior of google chrome. Ideal way will be use any proxy or to use packet sniffer such as Wireshark to see what request method, is used by chrome in subsequent request.

> Is this something related to the HTTP specs that only allow GET
> requests to be resumed?

As of now, there's no mention in spec of HTTP protocol, that only GET requests can be resumed.

> Or is it simply a design flaw in Chrome (and maybe other browsers as
> well) that makes it forget the original HTTP method used?

Yes, It's the flaw of google chrome. Make  sure that you check it on the latest version of Google chrome with all the update patches. Also check it on other browsers.

For more info about HTTP protocol, refer to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt.
Refer to following request, for serving partial response : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving

**Edit**
For more updated info regarding HTTP info, refer to :-
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230

Comment: I have used Fiddler in order to see that it used a GET request when trying to resume. Not sure if it always does that or if there is something on my server responses (headers, etc) that causes this behavior. But I will investigate a bit more and if it doesn't work I would probably have to find a workaround. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: RFC 2616 has been obsoleted two years ago.

Comment: @JulianReschke, Is the answer fine now ?